# Web2py SELECT option value

Tags: html, forms, html-select, web2py

In a controller in Web2Py I'm trying to populate a dropdown in a form with the results of a query. When the user submits the form I want to extract the *value* rather than the option name. I just can't seem to get the option value to appear in the dropdown.

I have this query:

```
course_list = external_db.executesql("SELECT course_id, course_title FROM course ORDER BY course_id")
```

and I have this table row:

```
form=FORM(TABLE(TR('course list: ' , SELECT(course_list, _name='courses', requires=IS_IN_SET(course_list, course_list_id, zero='- choose -'))),
```

but I can't find a way of only getting the value back from the option dropdown, rather than the option name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dido has the right idea. `course_list` is a list of `(value, label)` tuples, so you cannot simply pass it directly to `SELECT` to get the result you want. Another option is to construct the form using `SQLFORM.factory`, which is often easier than building a custom form manually via the `FORM` helper:

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('courses', 'integer',
                             requires=IS_IN_SET(course_list, zero='- choose -')))
```

The above will automatically generate the `SELECT` with the course titles as labels and the course IDs as values.

Comment: that sorted it, thanks so much, I'm really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use IS_IN_SET there to populate the dropdown. Use instead  OPTION helpers and loop over each tuple returned from your query to populate them:

```
options = [OPTION(course[1], _value=course[0]) for course in course_list]
form=FORM(TABLE(TR('course list: ', SELECT(options, _name='courses'))))
```

On submit retrieve the select value from **form.vars.courses**

Comment: Or with tuple unpacking: `[OPTION(label, _value=value) for value, label in course_list]`.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering dido, that is brilliant. I hadn't thought to look at the OPTION helper. The only thing now is that I get a (tuple index out of range) error for trying to access course[0] and course[1], even though clearly the course_id should be [0] and the course_title should be [1]

Comment: First of  Stuart, apply Anthony's advice and use tuple unpacking,  It's clearly better and easier to read.

Comment: Your query looks ok to me, can't say about that error; maybe try to update your question with more code.

Anyway I'm a big fan of SQLFORM.factory and I suggest strongly to look at Anthony answer too.

Comment: @dido I'm a convert to SQLFORM.factory, that sorted it. Thanks very much for your help!